# Trying to get an Eventlog file to be copied to another folder for backup purpose

Tags: c#, copy, event-log

I try to copy the EventLog "Application" to another folder on my PC but always get the error that

> "....Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Application.evtx..."

I use the code:

```
public void collectEventLogsFromSystem(string RequestedlogName,string newFolderPath)
{
    string combinedLogToFind =      "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Eventlog\\" + RequestedlogName;
    string LogEventsPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(combinedLogToFind, "File", null);
    if (LogEventsPath != null)
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(LogEventsPath, newFolderPath +"\\"+ RequestedlogName, true);               
    }

}//collectEventLogsFromSystem method
```

Even if i use explicit folder path it won't work:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(@"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Application.evtx", "c:\\ttt\\Application.evtx", true);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on StackOverflow which will probably solve your problem. I have a 64 bit machine which exhibited the same behavior. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958081/anyone-know-why-i-cant-access-the-winevt-folder-programmatically-in-c) by John Rasch solved the issue and explains why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the log file while the program is running, the way above will not work.  This post [Export Event Log (.evtx) without "run as administrator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134054/export-event-log-evtx-without-run-as-administrator) will allow you to backup the event log, even if you are currently using the event log in your application.