# Filter Logs Windows API : Export Event Log (.evtx) without "run as administrator"

Tags: c#, winapi, event-viewer

how to filter the windows event viewer logs retrieved using following method.
I want to fetch last one hour logs.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetLastError();

[DllImport("wevtapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EvtExportLog(IntPtr session, string channelPath, string query, string targetFilePath, int flags);

var success = EvtExportLog(IntPtr.Zero, "FilterLogs", "*", @"c:\temp\filtered_app_log.evtx", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to query and filter the event viewer logs.
I found the Microsoft MSDN document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtexportlog) and a connecting article, how to prepare XPath filter query from [XPath-Query](https://blog.backslasher.net/filtering-windows-event-log-using-xpath.html).

Just copy the XPath query and provide it as argument in the below code.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetLastError();

[DllImport("wevtapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EvtExportLog(IntPtr session, string channelPath, string query, string targetFilePath, int flags);

string query = "<QueryList><Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Application\"><Select Path=\"Application\"> *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;=3600000]]]</Select></Query></QueryList>";

var success = EvtExportLog(IntPtr.Zero, "FilterLogs", query, @"c:\temp\filtered_app_log.evtx", 1);
```

In my case I have filter the event for the last one hours. you can prepare filter following [XPath-Query](https://blog.backslasher.net/filtering-windows-event-log-using-xpath.html) article and provide it in the query.

Comment: thanks to the parent article I have referred, but did not find the query part so I have added it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134054/export-event-log-evtx-without-run-as-administrator