# WinEvent Logs and QFileSystemWatcher

Tags: windows, qt, logging, qt5, qfilesystemwatcher

I try to add WinEvent Logs Windows7 to QFileSystemWatcher.However, `addPath()` method return `false` value.

```
qDebug() << m_watcher->addPath("C:/Windows/System32/winevt/Logs/Application.evtx"); // false
```

The same i get after trying to add winevt folder:

```
qDebug() << m_watcher->addPath("C:/Windows/System32/winevt"); // false
```

Winevt folder has read-only attributes, and i can't modify it (after change,applying, closings and reopen attributes have old stay).
I read in QFileSystemWatcher documentation:

> Reasons for a watch failure are generally system-dependent, but may include the resource not existing, access failures, or the total watch count limit, if the platform has one.

But i have no idea how to find to source of failure and how it maybe fixed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the app as administrator?

Comment: Yes, but  it wasn't a reason. I find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution at another forum, where user give a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958201/4780422).

Sysnative folder is able to access.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you got a file system redirection on a 64 bits OS.

There are two ways to get around this:

1) Build your application as 64 bits.
2) Explicitly disable system redirection by calling `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`.

If you go to the second solution and need your application running on Windows XP 32 bits, i suggest you to call the WinAPI dynamically like on the following example:

```
#include <qt_windows.h>

#if defined(_WIN32) //Check if program is compiled in 32 bits (64 bits does not have redirection)
    SYSTEM_INFO SystemInfo = {0};
    GetNativeSystemInfo(&SystemInfo);

    if (SystemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64) //Check if processor is 64 bits
    {
        //Call the Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection api dynamically
        typedef BOOL(STDAPICALLTYPE *tWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)(PVOID);
        tWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection pWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = (tWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)QLibrary::resolve("Kernel32", "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
        if (pWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)
            pWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(NULL);
    }
#endif
```