# C# accessing winevt directory throws DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, io, directory

I'm trying to access the directory C:\Windows\System32\winevt in my code, but I get a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`.

**I read this thread:**
[Anyone know why I can't access the winevt folder programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958081/anyone-know-why-i-cant-access-the-winevt-folder-programmatically-in-c)

This implies that running a 32-bit application under a 64 bit operating system will re-direct me to **SystemWOW64** directory, and the resolution is to instead set my directory to `%windir%\Sysnative\winevt`. So I modified my code to conform to the answer provided in the aforementioned thread, except it still fails. I'm running **windows 10 enterprise 64-bit** and Sysnative doesn't exist.

**Example Code:**

This will return true:

```
            string directory = @"C:\Windows\System32";                  
            bool isDirectoryExists = Directory.Exists(directory);
```

This will return false:

```
            string directory = @"C:\Windows\System32\winevt";                  
            bool isDirectoryExists = Directory.Exists(directory);
```

There is no winevt directory in the directories System and SysWOW64, and Sysnative does not exist. So my question is, how do I get access to the winevt directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was looking for an actual folder called Sysnative in the Windows directory, I did not see it and therefore assume the code would not work. However I tested it anyway and `Directory.Exists` returned true. This is because Sysnative is a virtual folder.

Returns true:

```
        string directory = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\winevt";                  
        bool isDirectoryExists = Directory.Exists(directory);
```

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/sysnative-folder-in-windows-64-bit